# Como é possível trocar li de posição?

Tags: html, script

Como é possível trocar li de posição? Já tentei armazenar em arrays e usar métodos pra array mas não funcionou.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>teste</title>
<script></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="lista">
     <!-- preciso que o tem 1 vire o item 7, e o 7 vire o  1  -->

     <li class="prim">Item 1</li>
     <li class="prim">Item 2</li>
     <li class="prim">Item 4</li>
     <li class="prim">Item 5</li>
     <li class="prim">Item 6</li>
     <li class="prim">Item 7</li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se queres fazer por arraste do utilizador sugiro que uses uma biblioteca como o MooTools ou jQuery.

Se queres somente mudar de posição tens 2 possibilidades.

- mudar os conteúdos
- trocar os elementos `<li>` mantendo os elementos

### #1

Cria uma vriável que guarde o conteúdo de um deles e substitui os conteúdos:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul.lista li');
var temp = lis[0].innerHTML
lis[0].innerHTML = lis[5].innerHTML;
lis[5].innerHTML = temp;
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1w35ro2/1/

### #2

Usando o [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) podes colocar o nr.7 antes do nr.2, e usando o [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) ele coloca no final do elemento indicado.

a sintaxe é:

> elementoPai.**insertBefore**(novoElemento, elementoReferência);

Ou seja:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul.lista li');
lis[0].parentNode.insertBefore(lis[5], lis[1]); // para colocar o 7 no inicio 
lis[0].parentNode.appendChild(lis[0]);          // para colocar o 7 no inicio
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s1w35ro2/